# Pager Title Strip (Android 4.0) - Eclipse

Tags: android, webview, title, strip, pager

Last week I wanted to learn how to make an application for Android, so I downloaded the SDK, Eclipse and all the tools I was needing. I created a webapplication which I published in the Play Store.
Now I want to make something more complex, and I created a new project with "Swipe View+Title Strip" activity. 
I learned how to rename them, how to add many items in the menu and so on.
BUT I've got a big problem.
For example, how can I make each item in the menu to show a different webpage (using webview).
Please show me an example, so I can start learning.
I searched the web and I looked on the android development help, but couldn't find any help (just general terms).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone? Please I really need help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "swipe view+title strip" activity works about the same as any other activity. Perhaps it would be better to have buttons that have links to the webpages you want to view? I can't help much since I just started programming apps myself.